# Extract all types and their labels in English from DBPedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm trying to get all types from DBpedia using this SPARQL query:

```
select ?type {
   ?type a owl:Class .
}
```

Now, I want to also include the English label of each type returned by the query.  What do I need to add to my query?

Comment: Note that the answers to this question also provide a solution to the [your question from the comments of another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579620/extract-date-time-based-predicates-from-dbpedia#comment27385469_18594277).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to learn a bit more about how to retrieve arbitrary information from DBpedia.  Your first query (with a limit added) is:

```
select ?type {
   ?type a owl:Class .
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?type%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?type%20a%20owl%3aClass%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

One of the results is http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Animal, which you can actually visit in a web browser, and the corresponding page will display all of that resources properties.  For `animal`, there aren't all that many, but the ones of interest to us are

```
rdfs:label  Tier
rdfs:label  animal
rdfs:label  animal
rdfs:label  žival
rdfs:label  동물
```

The property that we're interested in here is `rdfs:label`, so we can extend the query to

```
select ?type ?label {
   ?type a owl:Class .
   ?type rdfs:label ?label .
}
limit 10
```

which we can actually abbreviate a little bit, using the semicolon:

```
select ?type ?label {
   ?type a owl:Class ;
         rdfs:label ?label .
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?type%20?label%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?type%20a%20owl%3aClass%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That query, though will return multiple results for each `?type`;  in fact, one per `?label`, so we get results including:

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Animal  "Tier"@de
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Animal  "animal"@en
```

Notice that the labels aren't simply strings, but are RDF literals with language tags.  In SPARQL, we can get the language tag of an RDF literal (if it has one) using the [`lang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lang) function.  It is possible to compare the language tag to `"en"` with the `=` operator, but a more robust solution is to use [`langMatches`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches), which will handle trickier cases like the one given in the documentation where

```
filter langMatches( lang(?title), "FR" )
```

can be used to find select both the following values for `?title`, whereas `filter( lang(?title) = "fr" )` would find only the first:

```
"Cette Série des Années Soixante-dix"@fr
"Cette Série des Années Septante"@fr-BE
```

Using langMatches, lang, and filter, we can update the query once more to

```
select ?type ?label {
   ?type a owl:Class ;
         rdfs:label ?label .
   filter(langMatches(lang(?label),"EN"))
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?type%20?label%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?type%20a%20owl%3aClass%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20filter%28langMatches%28lang%28?label%29,%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

which retrieves DBpedia types and their English labels.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT ?type (STR(?l) AS ?label) {
   ?type a owl:Class;
         rdfs:label  ?l .
   FILTER (LANG(?l) = "en")
}
```

Comment: For the language, a more robust solution is `filter(langMatches(lang(?label),"en"))`.