# SPARQL query to find only one value using the attribute

Tags: apache, sparql, rdf, rdfs, fuseki

I need to get the only the English value from my `rdfs:label` tag

Here is my sample RDF

```
<rdfs:label rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">English</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="fr">French</rdfs:label>
<rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Italy</rdfs:label>
```

I am currently using Apache Jena Fuseki server to perform the SPARQL query.  When I tried to get the rdfs:label it return me all three values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the query you tried?  Can you (re)present your data in Turtle, which aligns better to SPARQL -- and may show you your error?

Comment: That's not a legal RDF file (though it could be a snippet of one).  There's not enough there to actually specify any triples.

Comment: The answer to [Extract all types and their labels in English from DBPedia](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18733225/1281433) explains how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by the language tag you desire in your result.  A couple of ways to do this in SPARQL:

```
SELECT ?label
WHERE {
   ?s rdfs:label ?label .
   FILTER (lang(?label) = "en")
}
```

...or use SPARQL's `langMatches`:

```
SELECT ?label
WHERE {
   ?s rdfs:label ?label .
   FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en")
}
```

Comment: there is a typo in the second query : it should be variable ?s instead of ?sn

Comment: It should have been `?label`.  Thanks for letting me know1