# SPARQL query to extract all date/time data from DBPedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract all Subject/Predicate/Object from DBPedia endpoint using a SPARQL query which Predicate is a date/time prooperty.

I tried to parse DBPedia's Infobox Properties from the [Dump](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#raw-infobox-properties) and filter the statements using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579620/extract-date-time-based-predicates-from-dbpedia) query. But there are lots of objects which are not in correct date/time format (like 200 BC,...).

How can I query the Dump file or the DBPedia's endpoint to resolve all valid date/time based statements?

Comment: What do you mean by "Predicate is a date/time property"?  There was an earlier question about [finding time-values properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18579620/1281433), and the second code block in the accepted answer shows how you can get all the properties that have `xsd:dateTime` as their range.  Are you looking for more properties than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the earlier question showed how you can retrieve properties with a given datatype.  It's easy to extend this to get statements using that property.  That query bound `?p`; now just add `?s ?p ?o` to the query. E.g.:

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {
  ?p a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
     rdfs:range xsd:date .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?s%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?p%20a%20owl%3aDatatypeProperty%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3arange%20xsd%3adate%20.%0D%0A%20%20?s%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Do note what the [DBpedia 3.8 Downloads](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) page says about the “Raw Infobox Properties” and the “ONtology Infobox Properties” datasets:

> #### Raw Infobox Properties
>
> Information that has been extracted from Wikipedia infoboxes. Note
>   that this data is in the less clean /property/ namespace. The Ontology
>   Infobox Properties (/ontology/ namespace) should always be preferred
>   over this data.

> #### Ontology Infobox Properties
>
> High-quality data extracted from Infoboxes using the ontology-based
>   extraction. The predicates in this dataset are in the /ontology/
>   namespace. Used to be called Mapping Based Properties in previous
>   releases.
>
> *Note that this data is of much higher quality than the Raw Infobox
>   Properties in the /property/ namespace. For example, there are three
>   different raw Wikipedia infobox properties for the birth date of a
>   person. In the the /ontology/ namespace, they are all **mapped onto one
>   relation** http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate. It is a strong point
>   of DBpedia to unify these relations.*

It's not too surprising if you end up getting strange data values from the “Raw Infobox Properties”  data set.  You should really be using “Ontology Infobox Properties” instead.

Comment: @AmirPournasserian That link is down for me, at the moment, so I don't know what data is available through it.  I imagine that, unless DBpedia is doing some major restructuring, the same types of data will be available, i.e., a raw data set and an ontology data set.  If that's the case, then if you stick with the ontology data set, you should be fine.

Comment: @AmirPournasserian An announcement just went out to the DBpedia mailing list, and is also available online;  [DBpedia 3.9 is released](http://blog.dbpedia.org/2013/09/17/dbpedia-39-released-including-wider-infobox-coverage-additional-type-statements-and-new-yago-and-wikidata-links/)!  I'd check out that link and the rest of dbpedia.org;  it sounds like you should be able to use 3.9 now.